# How can I configure org-mode to collapse the results of code blocks by default?

Tags: org-mode

The default behaviour of `:results drawer` is that the results of a code block open in a collapsed state, which is perfect.

However, I would like this to be the default behaviour of the `#+RESULTS:` of code blocks that are generated by `:results code`.

Is there a way to have the `#+RESULTS:` of a code block generated by `:results code` to be in a collapsed state by default, when opening the document? (just like the default behaviour of `:results drawer`)

Comment: "...the results of a code block open in a collapsed state": not quite sure how you get this, but this does not happen in my case. The results drawer is unfolded until I explicitly fold drawers.

Comment: Do you know about the function `org-babel-result-hide-all`? You might want to add it as an "after" advice to one of the babel evaluation functions (perhaps `org-babel-eval` although I haven't checked to make sure). But don't you want to see the results of the evaluation? If not, why evaluate at all?

Comment: The results of my code is in a collapsed state because I use '#+STARTUP: content' in most of my org files and when I open a heading the ':results' drawer is actually collapsed. You are right if I open an org file without the '#+STARTUP: content', it's not the case that it's collapsed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that function, it works perfectly! The reason I want to hide the results is because it makes it easier to navigate the document at times.